# Array of eight random Integers where each Integer has a difference of at least 15 from all others in the array?

Tags: java, random, range, distance

I am trying to write a method that creates and returns an array of random `Integer`s that has a length of eight and is within the range `[25, 725]`.

Every `Integer` in the array must be higher or lower than every other `Integer` in the array by at least 15. However, my method isn't returning arrays that meet this requirement.

I set up a `main()` method that checks the output of my method 100,000 times, and throws an `Exception` if there are any `Integers` that are too close.

*How can I create a method that will return an array of `Integers` where the difference between every `Integer` and every other `Integer` is at least 15?*

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       Integer[] distances = new Integer[8];

       for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

          distances = createPlanetDistances(distances.length);

          // check distances for values within 15
          for (int x = 0; x < distances.length; x++) {

             for (int y = 0; y < distances.length; y++) {

                if (x == y)
                   continue;

                if (Math.abs(distances[x] - distances[y]) < 15) {

                   System.out.println(distances[x] + " " + distances[y]);
                   throw new Exception("Doesn't work");
                }
             }
          }

          for (int distance : distances)
             System.out.print(distance + " ");

          System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
       }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an array of distances-from-the-sun for a given number of Planets.
     * It does not allow distances to be within 15 of any other distance.
     *
     * @param planetAmount The number of distances to return.
     * @return An array of distances-from-the-sun.
     */
    private static Integer[] createPlanetDistances(int planetAmount) {

       SplittableRandom random = new SplittableRandom();

       final int min = 25;
       final int max = 726;

       HashSet<Integer> distanceSet = new HashSet<>();

       // make sure there are no duplicate Integers

       for(int i = 0; i < planetAmount; i++) {

          int num = random.nextInt(min, max);

          while (distanceSet.contains(num))
             num = random.nextInt(min, max);

          distanceSet.add(num);
       }

       // make sure each distance is 15 away from all others

       Integer[] distances = distanceSet.toArray(new Integer[]{});

       for(int i = 0; i < distances.length; i++) {

          // check distances[i] with all other Integers
          for (int j = 0; j < distances.length; j++) {

             // do not compare an element with itself
             if (j == i)
                continue;

             int difference = Math.abs(distances[i] - distances[j]);

             if (difference < 15) {

                while (difference < 15) {

                   distances[i] = random.nextInt(min, max);
                   difference = Math.abs(distances[i] - distances[j]);
                }

                // check all Integers again
                System.out.println("HERE " + i + " " + j);
                i = 0;
                break;
             }
          }
       }

       return distanceSet.toArray(new Integer[]{});
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your solution?

Comment: @Turing85 it returns Integers in the same array that have a difference of less than 15.

Comment: take the last `int`, add `15` to it, then add some random `int > 0` to it.

Comment: @Turing85 All of the Integers must have a difference of at least 15 from all other Integers in the same array.

Comment: Create the array. Sort the array. Go through the array comparing differences and increment as needed. Shuffle the array.

Comment: @LuminousNutria since my proposal generates `int`s in an ascending order, your constraint will not be violated.

Comment: @Turing85 I think I may be misunderstanding what you mean then. Perhaps you could write an answer?

Comment: `distances[i] = distances[i - 1] + 15 + random.nextInt(15);` (this will generate distances between `15` and `30` more than the previous distance)

Comment: What is the value range? If you select 8 random numbers between 0 and 1000000000, then you're unlikely to find numbers that are close to each other.

Comment: In the half-open range (25 to 726], correct?

Comment: @DavidConrad It should be the integer range [25, 725], or any integers within [25, 726)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find `COUNT` numbers in range `MIN` to `MAX` (exclusive) that are more than `DISTANCE` apart, build a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and use the [`ceiling(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#ceiling-E-) method to find nearby values.

*Example*

```
final int DISTANCE = 15, MIN = 25, MAX = 726, COUNT = 8;

ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
TreeSet<Integer> numbers = new TreeSet<>();
while (numbers.size() < COUNT) {
    int value = random.nextInt(MIN, MAX);
    Integer ceiling = numbers.ceiling(value - DISTANCE);
    if (ceiling == null || ceiling > value + DISTANCE)
        numbers.add(value);
}
System.out.println(numbers);
```

*Sample Output*

```
[86, 104, 120, 369, 425, 532, 682, 713]
```

You can always shuffle the result if you don't want them in ascending order.

*How It Works*

The `ceiling` method returns the least value in the set greater than or equal to the given value, or null if there is no such value.

So if e.g. `value` is 134 and `DISTANCE` is 15, then `ceiling(value - DISTANCE)` will find the smallest value that is >= 119. If that value is >= 149, then we know the nearby range 119-149 is clear and we can use the 134 value.

Comment: Seems like overkill to use a tree lookup for this, no? Still a clever approach.

Comment: Why did you use a `for(;;)` statement with a break instead of `while(numbers.size() != COUNT)`?

Comment: @LuminousNutria I could, but then it would check the size even when no new number was added. But you're right, the performance difference is minuscule. Guess I had that left in after refactoring the code from an earlier attempt using nested loops. Code updated, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I didn't consider the performance difference. Out of curiosity, would `while(true)` also be slower than `for(;;)`?

Comment: @LuminousNutria `while(true)` and `for (;;)` and `for (; true; )` all generate the exact same bytecode. --- I prefer `for (;;) { ... }` because it easily reads as `forever { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You are generating planetary orbits, so it should be OK to have monotonically increasing numbers. Each number you generate has constraints imposed on it by the following numbers, and in turn imposes constraints on them once it is generated.

**Constraint:** If you want to generate `N` orbits between `min` and `max` separated by `D`, then your bounds for the first orbit are `[min, max - D * (N - 1)]`. This is simply because you can't pack the following `N - 1` planets into a space that is less than `D * (N - 1)`.

You can update the second constraint as you go, since the new minimum is going to be the last generated number + `D`. Here is a simple `O(n)` implementation (assuming that genrating a random number is `O(1)`):

```
final int DISTANCE = 15, MIN = 25, MAX = 726, COUNT = 8;
Random random = Random();

orbits = new int[COUNT];

if(MAX - MIN < DISTANCE * COUNT) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insert pithy comment about COUNT");
}

min = MIN;
for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
    max = MAX - DISTANCE * (COUNT - i - 1);
    orbits[i] = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    min = orbits[i] + DISTANCE;
}
```

Comment: Although that works, it will not generate an even distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach avoids acceptance/rejection sampling by removing the spacing requirement, generating values uniformly over the correspondingly shortened range, adding the spacing gaps back, and shuffling to yield the results in a randomized order.

```
static Random r = new Random();

public static ArrayList<Integer>
    gen_array(int lower_bound, int upper_bound, int n, int separation) {
    upper_bound -= (n - 1) * separation;

    if(upper_bound < lower_bound) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Infeasible arguments");
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> ary = new ArrayList<>();
    while(ary.size() < n) {
        ary.add(lower_bound + r.nextInt(upper_bound - lower_bound + 1));
    }
    Collections.sort(ary);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        ary.set(i, ary.get(i) + i * separation);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(ary);
    return ary;
}
```

If you call it with a value of 8 for `n`, a `lower_bound` of 25, an `upper_bound` of 130, and a `separation` of 15, it yields the correct result immediately where an acceptance/rejection approach could take an awful lot of iterations to cough up the unique set of values for the answer.